group by date and get total profit
Excel table

i have a data of my closed transaction. i am doing analysis. here we have different lot size with different profit. lot size starts from 0.01, 0.02, 0.04, 0.08, etc.

i want to group these by date so i can see what is my daily profit.
then, the tricky part is, i want to see what my daily profit is if i filter the lot size eg. what is my daily profit if i filter <0.02? and <0.04? and so on.

i know this is too much to ask but i did try to do but failed. i tried using pivot table but also failed.
attached image is part of the data but it has over 1000 rows
edit:

@gns100 you are right, my pivot doesnt work cos i forgot to add something in the filter. now i get what i want. unfortunately i cant attached a file here but whoever want i can upload a github repo

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Look into Pivot tables

This should be a straight forward pivot table. I see the close time going into the rows section, the profit into the values, and size going either into the columns or filters section. If that doesn't work then, please attach a screenshot of your pivot table including the pivot tables fileds section. You might also create a mock up of what you would like to see.

It would be better if you presented your data as a text table which can be easily copy/pasted. More people will take a look if they don't have to laboriously retype your data into a worksheet.

@gns100 thanks for the input!
